# Encode string field to base64 in Tableau

Tags: encoding, base64, tableau-api

Can I somehow encode string field into base64 field using Tableau Desktop only?

I didn't find any function for this, probably there is a way to do it.

Comment: This is a rather unique question. Base64 encoding is a way to represent binary data as ASCII text for transferring binary data across a network. What binary data do you need to show in Tableau?

Comment: I need to encode a part of url link. This is needed to use some service called Affilitest. Tableau report users can click the link and go through this service. I can provide example of raw link and encoded link, but not sure because they are pretty big.

Comment: I'm familiar with Tableau's URL linking ability. Are you sure it's base64 encoding and note Http encoding you need? Base64 is for transferring binary data and you usually don't do that with a URL; it's usually a POST request. A link example would be helpful as long as it doesn't contain sensitive info.